# What is the right way to draw attention to old meta posts if edit is no option?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Related:

- [How to move up/*bump* questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82271/how-to-move-up-bump-questions-on-stack-overflow)
- [How to (politely) bump a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/how-to-politely-bump-a-question)
- [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions)

To summarize the related questions:

- <s>Offer a bounty</s> (This is not possible on Meta)
- <s>Edit/Improve the the question</s> (One [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82271/how-to-move-up-bump-questions-on-stack-overflow) says, it is *considered abuse of the system.* Also not always a question can be improved).

So to the question:

What would be correct way to draw attention to a question, for example for a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? What is the situation, if the question can not be further be improved, if that is the answer?

Comment: upvote it. Or go work for the company and press your case at their standups.

Comment: the problem with upvote is, it does not directly draw attention. The last one is for obviously reasons not possible :D @RobertLongson

Comment: It does in the aggregate, you just need lots of other people to agree with you as they come across the request. Sometimes there's no obvious way to throw your weight around when you're not paying for something.

Comment: Yeah...go upvote a 7-year-old feature-request. That'll make all the difference /s

Comment: Upvoting the post and brining it up in relevant discussions on meta would draw more people towards that post.

Comment: The usual answer seems to be "make a new meta post." It wasn't that long ago that I saw a meta post asking for a feature, only to be linked to a 3-year old post asking for the feature, which was itself linked to a 6-year old post asking for the feature.  All three were pretty heavily up-voted and with no response from SO staff.